# How to stop calling the api again and again using react useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am using the redux toolkit, after adding the product dependency it is calling the API rapidly. How can I stop calling the API again and again?

Comment: Please include your code in your question, as copyable text instead of an image

Comment: Why is `products` a dependency if you don't need it inside `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Remove it as a dependency. if you only want dispatch when component first time render then use empty brackets `[]`

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
}, []);
```

2. Use the `useMemo` hook, then the component will be rendered only the products have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it as a dependency, if you only want to call it once when the component mounts just have an empty dependency. like this...

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove dispatch in dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    

}, [products])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.